# NOT NULL constraint failed: SendMessage_users.UserName in django and sqlite3

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am just started my django beginner tutorial and facing problem with inserting data into sq lite database. while loading the page AddUser it says;

> IntegrityError at /AddUser/ NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   SendMessage_users.UserName
>
> Users.objects.create(UserID = User_ID , UserName = User_Name, Email =
>   User_Email ,Phone = User_Phone)

The model.py is

```
class Users(models.Model):
    UserID = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='User ID',max_length=255,primary_key=True)
    UserName = models.CharField(verbose_name='User Name',max_length=254)
    Email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Email',max_length=254)
    Phone = models.CharField(verbose_name='Phone Number',max_length=254)
```

and the view.py is

```
def add_user(request):
    User_ID = request.POST.get('UserID')
    User_Name = request.POST.get('UserName')
    User_Email = request.POST.get('Email')
    User_Phone = request.POST.get('Phone')
    Users.objects.create(UserID = User_ID , UserName = User_Name, Email = User_Email ,Phone = User_Phone)
    return render_to_response('add_user.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and add_user.html is

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block Content %}

<div class="container">
  <!-- Contacts -->
  <div id="contacts">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Alignment -->
      <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-4">
        <!-- Form itself -->
        <form name="AddUsers" action="" method="POST" class="well" id="contactForm"  novalidate>
          {% csrf_token %}
          <legend>Send Messages</legend>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" class="form-control"
              placeholder="Subject" id="UserID" name="UserID" required
              data-validation-required-message="Please enter UserID" />
              <p class="help-block"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" class="form-control"
              placeholder="Subject" id="UserName" name="UserName" required
              data-validation-required-message="Please enter UserName" />
              <p class="help-block"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" class="form-control"
              placeholder="Subject" id="Email" name="Email" required
              data-validation-required-message="Please enter Email" />
              <p class="help-block"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" class="form-control"
              placeholder="Subject" id="Phone" name="Phone" required
              data-validation-required-message="Please enter Phone" />
              <p class="help-block"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="success"> </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right">Send</button><br />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because when you make a GET request to that url, the view it's trying to get data from the POST data, which obviously doesn't exist at the time and it's trying to create an object with this 'none' data. In the view you have to make a difference for each request method you are expecting (GET and POST I'm assuming), by checking the request.method value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
models.Users.objects.create()
```